# Old scanner isn't even recognized on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, scanner

My father finally bought a new laptop. However, his old scanner didn't work in his new one, so he gave it to my brother. It worked like a charm on my brothers 8 years old pc, until he bought a new one. I took the scanner and plugged it in, but it doesn't even show a notice about new scanner.

I'm curious if this (old but very good) scanner can still be used. Is there some kind of tricks to do?

Comment: You might consider posting the make and model of the scanner

Answer (score 3):

You're most likely out of luck. Scanners seem to be notoriously picky when it comes to drivers; they're usually the first to fail after an OS upgrade. If you have Windows 7 Professional or Ultimate, however, you might have a chance at getting the scanner to work installing it in Windows XP Mode (I'm not sure, though). I've installed hardware in Windows XP running in VMWare Player, so I know it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Vista & 7 uses a different driver model than Windows XP.

This is one of the reasons why Vista was not widely approved of.

Many secondary (& some primary) peripheral makers chose not to update the drivers for their older products and unless you are able to write your own drivers for Win 7 you are out of luck.

For instance, I had a video card that worked well in XP but when it was installed in Windows 7, the OS wouldn't even recognize the card and I had to buy a new card.

If XP mode is available on your version of Windows 7 you *might* be able to install the scanner in XP mode, but I am not certain.